# WooCommerce plugins permalinks？

Tags: plugins

I use WooCommerce.
My links are looking like this at the moment:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/shop/sample-product/
```

but I want them to be like this:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/shop/1.html/
http://www.mywebsite.com/shop/2.html/
http://www.mywebsite.com/shop/3.html/
http://www.mywebsite.com/shop/4.html/
http://www.mywebsite.com/shop/5.html/
http://www.mywebsite.com/shop/x.html/
```

how do I change them?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want this?
I can't see any good reason. It's much better for both usability and SEO to have the titles in the permalinks.
But if you REALLY want this, you can use "/shop/%post_id%.html" as a product permalink base. You change this under "Settings" -> "Permalinks" and then at the bottom under the section "Product permalink base". Put the following as a "Custom Base":

/shop/%post_id%.html

Comment: Thank you.I come from China.The China Products name is too long，I follow what you say，but the links become like this：/shop/%post_id%.html/sample-product/

Answer (score 0):

I tried answer by [Pekz0r](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/27468/pekz0r) and It work if you used it with wordpress post but for woocommerce product it did not work maybe because the setting of wocommerce permalink defined just the url base which is url prefixes, I think you need to write your own rule in .htaccess

check http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks for more info on permalinks and sample .htaccess